# C4477 - format string '%s' requires type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'

Tags: c

I have been stalking the forums for more than a month now and it has answers to most of my questions. But I have been struggling through one difficulty which I couldn't really find the answer around here(there is other similar solutions, but it didn't not solved mine)

I have tried to simplify my huge code block to the one shown below,

```
#define DATA_ROW 1 /*I have one data per line*/


int freqstring;
char objectstring;
char string[10];
FILE * file;


freqstring = 0;
while (fscanf_s(file, "%s", &objectstring, 8) == DATA_ROW)
{
    string[freqstring] = objectstring;
    freqstring = freqstring + 1;
}

for (freqstring = 0; freqstring < 10; freqstring = freqstring + 1)
{
    printf("%s", string[freqstring]);
}
```

Started learning C programming for over 2 months now, and this is the first time I'm using arrays. And I've encountered the following error message in the output box

> warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'

Comment: `"%s", string[freqstring])` - something is missing here...

Comment: The error is quite clear: you're claiming you want to print a "string", meaning a char array or a char pointer. The parameter you are giving is a char. Not an array, not a pointer.

Comment: I have corrected all typos. @SamiKuhmonen, but doesn't declaring my it as 'char string[10]' made it an array, with name string, with size 10? I am sorry if my question sounded really dumb to you.

Comment: Yes, but you're not giving `string` to printf, you're giving `string[freqstring]` which is a single char in that array.

Comment: Looks like I'm missing out something big here. Doesn't it when I make the for loop and printf the `string[freqstring]` means I'll print each element in that array while increasing by 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding of the string concept.

A string is a zero-terminated array of chars. The individual char in that string is still integer type.

So `string[freqstring]` has integer type. And that is exactly what the error message says. The `printf` expects a `char*` type (aka string) due to use of `%s` but you give it an integer type.

To get the string, just use `string`, i.e.

```
printf("%s\n", string);
```

Further, it seems you have problems with the scanning:

```
fscanf_s(file, "%s", &objectstring, 8)
```

You ask for a string (`%s`) but `objectstring` is just a single `char`. You claim the size is 8 which it isn't. Use `sizeof` instead of a constant.

Did you really intend to read chars, then use `%c` instead of `%s`.

**In case you want to read chars**, the code could be something like:

```
freqstring = 0;
string[freqstring] = '\0';
while ((fscanf_s(file, "%c", &objectstring, sizeof(char)) == 1) &&
       (freqstring < 9))
{
    string[freqstring] = objectstring;
    freqstring = freqstring + 1;
    string[freqstring] = '\0';
}

printf("%s\n", string);
```

Comment: I know that '\0' terminates the string. But I have other questions,
What exactly does the third line in the while loop means? Does it add a '\0' behind the row of characters that I've scanned?

And why don't I need to do the for loop on the second part? Is it because you've done it in such a way that everything is considered to be one string? And all you got to do is print that string?

Comment: Oh and by the way, my initial plan was to create a very large text file with words and numbers in each line, i.e. _work 10_. So I don't think getting character by character would be the best way for me, since my plan was to fscanf_s %s %d and store it into an array, so I can slowly arrange, and analyse the elements in that array.

Comment: @AndrewWong - For you first comment: Correct, the third line adds the zero-termination which is required for a string. Then you can print the whole string in one go. That is what `%s` is all about, i.e keep printing chars until a zero-termination is reached. So your second loop isn't needed. You could use the second loop but in that case you should print a char at the time using `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: @AndrewWong - For you second comment: I would use `fgets` to read a whole line into a string. After that I would break the string into a word and a vaule which I would store in a struct (or rather array of struct). But that is kind of a new question, you could ask. I hope the above answer helped.

Comment: How do you separate a word and a value(which is an element of the array, I assumed?) into a string(I've always assumed the data type for a word is string, correct me if I'm wrong) and an integer? _My professor said he had not taught us the use of struct, and we are allowed to use it, but if we were to have flaws in our layout of struct, we will be marked down relatively more significantly than having flaws in arrays only. He mentioned that our assignment can be solved with arrays only_

Comment: Er, this answer states several times that characters in the string are of `int` type.  No, an individual character in a string is an *integer* type, but it is of type `char`, not `int`.  It is *widened* to an `int` because [that's how variadic functions work](http://www.c-faq.com/varargs/promos.html).

Comment: @jamesdlin - true, the wording `integer type` is probably more accurate.